# Can write to google cloud storage from one machine but not

Tags: google-cloud-platform, next.js, google-cloud-storage, vercel

I have a weird bug where I'm able to write to my cloud storage bucket from one machine but not another. I can't tell if the issue is vercel or if it's my configurations but the app is deployed on vercel so it should be the same no matter where I'm accessing it.

`upload.ts`

```
  export const upload = async (req: IncomingMessage, userId: string) => {
    const storage = new Storage({
      // credentials
    });
    const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.GCS_BUCKET_NAME as string);
    const form = formidable();
    const { files } = await parseForm(form, req);
    const file = files.filepond;
    const { path } = file;
    const options = {
      destination: `products/${userId}/${file.name}`,
      preconditionOpts: {
        ifGenerationMatch: 0
      }
    };
    await bucket.upload(path, options);
  }
```

Again, my app is deployed on Vercel and I'm able to upload images on my own machine but can't do it if I try on my phone or another pc/mac. My cloud storage bucket is also public so I should be able to read/write to it from anywhere. Any clues?

Comment: Different things: Firstly, having a bucket public is not a problem if it's only for reading data (like images, website,...). However, never open publicly a bucket with write permission to all users: anyone will be able to store data in it, maybe illegal data, or at least a large volume of data that will cost a lot!!

Comment: Then, what's your error when you say "I can't" on your cell phone or your PC. Do you have a permission issue? Most of the time, the bucket is marked PUBLIC on GCS because it's open for reading, not for writing. Your vercel environment maybe have the permission to write, not the other platform.

Comment: Yeah it's sort of a weird issue. Here's the scenario, you can log into my app via a google provider provided by next-auth. You're able to create listings which allow for an image to be uploaded to cloud storage. When I create a listing and upload from my own computer it'll write to cloud storage but if I try to do the same from another device, even though i'm logged into the same gmail account, the image won't be written to cloud storage.